# Non empty MDX query in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mdx

My issue is when I use `non empty` on the row, all row fields disappear from the data set in `Visual Studios 2010`. The same happens if I place `non empty` on columns -- all the column fields disappear from the data set. If the `non empty` is removed from the statement, all rows and column return to the data set.

This query runs as expected in SQL management studios, but not in `Visual Studios`. Could someone shed some light on this please?

I've posted just the select query portion below:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Quantity - Starting Date Range]
   ,Receipts
   ,[Cost of Sales]
   ,[Samples]
   ,[Donations]
   ,[Movement Journals]
   ,[Subtotal Qty Rollforward]
   ,[Quantity - Ending Date Range]
   ,[Qty Rollforward vs AX Difference]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Released products].[Product number].[Product number].MEMBERS*
      [Released products].[Product name].[Product name].MEMBERS*
      [Sites].[Sites - name].[Sites - name].MEMBERS*
      [Warehouses].[Warehouses - name].[Warehouses - name].MEMBERS*
      [Inventory batches].[Expiration date].[Expiration date].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [aCube];
```

Comment: Please post the output from SSMS and VS please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NON EMPTY` removes all empty(null) values from the selected axes. If you have empty/null values, you won't be seeing them upon using this keyword.

Comment: That thought floated pass my mind last night. Thanks for confirming!